# Firefox/Google Chrome extension to darken pages & reduce eye strain

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the Firefox add-on to dim the whole page of a site?](https://superuser.com/questions/51074/whats-the-firefox-add-on-to-dim-the-whole-page-of-a-site)

Is there an extension or add-on like [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) which lets you easily toggle back and forth between affected (Stylish) and standard (or untainted) view?

I've tried changing colors in Firefox (Settings > Content > Colors) but there is no quick toggle between the states.

Firefox or Google Chrome, whichever one has the extension. Doesn't matter since I'll switch to using that as my primary development browser.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/51074/whats-the-firefox-add-on-to-dim-the-whole-page-of-a-site

Comment: also worth noting that blackout doesnt work on the latest firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on the stylish icon in the Firefox statusbar you can disable styles that it is applying.

Comment: ah, didn't see it down there!

can anyone recommend any styles for stylish?

Comment: @megafish - this site is not a forum, it is a place for individual questions and answers to them. As such, you shouldn't ask a new question in a comment, but as a new question. If this answer is a solution to your problem, mark it as accepted.